# Live Preview only works for Entry variable?

Tags: templating, control-panel, live-preview

Is there an undocumented shortcoming of Live Preview? Seems to only work where the entry variable is concerned.

I'm using a Structure section to create pages with "Chapters". The section (let's call it **Areas**) has a Max Level of 2. The idea is that level 1 entries  load a template that calls the content from all of that entry's children.

For instance, Areas looks like this in the CP:

```
Learning
-- Our Approach
-- Design Patterns
-- etc.
```

The front-end works just fine. `/areas/learning` loads the `areas/_entry` template where I call all of the entry's children and output their content to the page.

The issue is in Live Preview when editing a child entry, such as **Our Approach**. It looks like Live Preview only likes using the provided `entry` variable, but will not update anything nested, found in a loop, or otherwise loaded into the template's context.

For instance, this simplified template code, while rendering as expected, does not update in Live Preview:

```
{% if craft.request.isLivePreview %}
    {% set myEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}
{% endif %}

{% set chapters = myEntry.children %}

{{ myEntry }}
<ul>
{% for chapter in chapters %}
    <li>{{chapter}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I renamed the entry variable as per [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1644/1027). Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just changed this behavior in [Craft 2.3.2616](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2616):

> Live Preview and Share links will now show the unpublished entry/category changes wherever the entry/category are being referenced in the templates (even areas where the entry/category was fetched from the database).

So now Live Preview (and Share links) should work as expected for you.

Comment: I like this kind of answers!

Comment: this is amazing! thanks for listening Brandon :). Sorry @carlcs, but I'll have to change the correct answer to this one, since I went back and updated my template to reflect this change.

Comment: No way, @noSlouch! Now that I was so creative and found a solution for this, I insist that YOU stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Thanks to P&T this workaround is not necessary any more with [Craft 2.3.2616](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2616)!

*This was my temporary solution / bugfix:*

---

I think you're right, Live Preview seems to only update if changes to the automatically provided `entry` EntryModel are detected.

So this causes problems with Live Preview:

```
{# Get `entry` manually #}
{% set home = craft.entries.section('home').first() %}
{{ home.welcome }}
```

while this works fine:

```
{{ entry.welcome }}
```

To get Live Preview working with your Chapters example, you'd need to somehow make the connection to the `entry` variable.

What I came up with is this: you still loop through the `chapters` returned from your `craft.entries` call. But within the loop you conditionally overwrite the `chapter` variable in case it matches your current `entry` EntryModel.

I also replaced `getSegment()` with `getAncestors()`, to not rely on any specific paths / routes that might change in the future:

```
{# Get the top level entry #}
{% if entry.level != 1 %}
    {% set rootEntry = entry.getAncestors().first() %}
{% else %}
    {% set rootEntry = entry %}
{% endif %}

{{ rootEntry.body }}

{% set chapters = rootEntry.children %}
{% for chapter in chapters %}

    {# Bugfix for live preview #}
    {% if chapter.id == entry.id %}{% set chapter = entry %}{% endif %}

    {{ chapter.body }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: nailed it! Thanks for rooting this out. I think this qualifies as a bug?

Comment: @noSlouch yeah, maybe it's a bug. But I think it's more likely that this is simply how Live Preview works right now. It definitely qualifies as a feature request though!

Comment: I'll add something to the G+ page